# What does the word "foil" mean?

Tags: meaning

What does the word "foil" mean in the following quote from the New York Times?

> Some Republican strategists say Mr. Trump might be missing an opportunity to be seen standing up to anti-Trump sentiment.
>   “You’d be well served to come to California and speak to his base back in Wisconsin and Michigan and Pennsylvania,” said Rob Stutzman, a California Republican strategist who works out of Sacramento.
>   “This is a president that loves foils,” Mr. Stutzman said. “California would be a great foil for him.”

Comment: Please include the research you have done in general reference.

Answer (score 1):

Foil has many meanings.  In this quotation from the NYT, foil means:

> One that stands in contrast to and emphasizes the distinctive
>   characteristics of another: "I am resolved my husband shall not be a
>   rival, but a foil to me" (Charlotte Bronte

Source: [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/foil)

Other examples, cited by the The Free Dictionary (link above):

[Bleak House](https://dickens.thefreelibrary.com/Bleak-House/33-1#foil) by Charles Dickens (at end of the long excerpt):

> Mr. Tulkinghorn, such a foil in his old- fashioned rusty black to Lady
>   Dedlock's brightness, hands her down the staircase to her carriage.

[Wuthering Heights](https://brontee.thefreelibrary.com/Wuthering-Heights/1-18#foil), by Emily Bronte:

> However, it must be acknowledged, she had faults to foil her gifts.

My final quote is quite sexist, but it illustrates better than the others what Rob Stutzman was probably thinking, and has the virtue of not being a 19th century quote, although I can't say the same about the mindset:

> pretty girls like plain friends as foils. [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/foil)

Judge for yourself who Mr. Stutzman would think is pretty and who is plain in his statement.

Answer (score 0):

A foil is "a light fencing sword having usually a circular guard and a flexible blade tapering to a blunt point." Webster's New Collegiate. In your context foil means an opponent who will provide Mr. Trump with the opportunity of demonstrating his political skills without getting mortally wounded (blunt point). Someone who will draw out the best Mr. Trump has to offer.

The use of foil in this context is an example of metonymy, where the name of one thing is used to represent another of which it is a part or associated with.

Answer (score 0):

> **Examples from literature**
>   In Frankenstein, by Mary Shelley, the two main characters: Dr. Frankenstein and his "creature" are both together literary foils, functioning to compare one to the other.
>   In Jane Austen's Pride and Prejudice, Mary's absorption in her studies places her as a foil to her sister Lydia Bennet's lively and distracted nature.
>
> Similarly, in Shakespeare's play Julius Caesar, the character Brutus has foils in the two characters Cassius and Mark Antony.
>
> In the Harry Potter series, Draco Malfoy can be seen as a foil to the Harry Potter character; Professor Snape enables both characters "to experience the essential adventures of self-determination" but they make different choices; Harry chooses to oppose Lord Voldemort and the Death Eaters, whereas Draco eventually joins them.
>   Source:  [Wikipedia  Foil (literature)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foil_(literature))

These examples demonstrate the concept of one person serving as a "foil" to another—as in the New York Times statement about Trump.  A foil is often an opponent or otherwise a study in contrasts with respect to the main character.